# Артефакты после скругления углов, pywin32

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, kivy, pywin32

Есть минимальный код на `python kivy` + `pywin32`. Используется функция `CreateRoundRectRgn` для создания региона с скругленными углами, после чего этот регион назначается моему окну через `SetWindowRgn`. Как можно убрать артефакты [image: вот они] на углах?

```
import os
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32api

os.environ['PYTHONFAULTHANDLER'] = '1'

from additive import createDirs, writer

createDirs(["config",], True)
writer(0, 1)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

TemplateDir = resource_path('styles/')
for file in os.listdir(TemplateDir):
    Builder.load_file(TemplateDir+file)

from LocalScreen import LocalScreen as LS

from userWidgets import TB

class FastMessageApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FastMessageApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        Window.size = (500, 400)
        Window.set_title("FastMessage")

        self.HWND = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "FastMessage")
        self.RoundedRegion = win32gui.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, 500, 400, 50, 50)
        win32gui.SetWindowRgn(self.HWND, self.RoundedRegion, True)
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(self.HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32gui.GetWindowLong(self.HWND, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(self.HWND, win32api.RGB(0,0,0), 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

        self.__Manager = ScreenManager(transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.1), size_hint = (1,0.95), pos_hint = {'bottom': 1})

    def build(self):
        self.__Window = FloatLayout()
        self.__Window.add_widget(TB())
        self.__Window.add_widget(self.__Manager)
        return self.__Window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = FastMessageApp()
    app.run()
```